# Hall Conductivity of Maxwell Action

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, condensed-matter

I am currently reading David Tong's [notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qhe.html) on Chern-Simon's theory and below equation (5.5), he makes the statement:

> "The action (5.5) has no Hall conductivity because this is ruled out in d = 3+1 dimensions on rotational grounds."

Why is this true?

Comment: Well, section 5.1 in David Tong's notes is essentially structured as an argument for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides calculating the Hall conductivity directly from the Maxwell action and showing it to be zero, the more general argument is the following.

The important point is that conductivity is a rank-2 tensor, i.e. a tensor with two indices and transforms appropriately under spatial rotations. Once you see this, there are two ways to argue that Hall conductivity is zero.

1. You want a tensor that is invariant under rotations due to the rotational symmetry in this problem. Such a tensor must be proportional to the identity tensor, therefore it cannot have off-diagonal components.
2. The Hall conductivity is the anti-symmetric part of the conductivity tensor. In three dimensions, there are three independent parameters for the antisymmetric part. You can show that the antisymmetric part is closed under rotations and it transforms as a [pseudovector](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector) (other examples of pseudovectors in three dimensions are angular momentum and magnetic field). You cannot have a non-zero pseudovector that is rotationally symmetric, just like vectors.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am not familiar with the covector discussion. Are you saying that any anti-symmetric tensor transforms as a covector? And what did you mean by the last remark "just like vectors". Instead, if you could point me to some references on this discussion, that would be equally as helpful.

Comment: Yes that is what I am saying, but maybe pseudovector is the appropriate word. I think Wikipedia has a good discussion. I said just like vectors because you cannot have a non zero vector that is invariant under rotations.